# Styling divs as tables, acceptable?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a template, and I know using CSS is better than using HTML tables for positioning... But, is it acceptable to get the best of both worlds and use table-like styles on my divs? For example:

```
display: table;
```

This would not only help me solve the sticky footer problem, but I could avoid the pains associated with floats as well. Not sure if this would be considered an ugly hack or an eloquent solution. Thoughts?

Comment: honestly saying if you go with html tables you need to stick to css , after all look and feel is extremely important

Comment: You could get a lot of interesting opinions on this over at programmers.stackexchange.com, but this feels more like an opinion question than one with a clear cut answer.

Comment: I, too, feel dirty when I first heard of this and tried it but I haven't figured out why yet.

Comment: `Display: table` is free to be used without restriction on any element you please.  The table tag, however, should be restricted for marking up tabular data only.

Comment: Already there are a few conflicting opinions below (none of which are objectively right or wrong). Have you consider closing or migrating this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally see nothing wrong with using `display: table`.  I would not recommend widespread use of it, but sometimes it can be very useful for making something display the way you want without having to add a bunch of extra HTML or deal with an onerous set off CSS rules to get something to look the way you want it to.

If it works for the client browsers you are targeting in your development and can save you pain or complexity in other areas, than feel free to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly hack... You can deal with floats using the *clearfix* method and there are tons of sticky footer techniques ( like [this](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) one ) to use.

Also the `display: table` [not supported in IE7 and below](http://caniuse.com/#search=%20table) if that's a concern.

You should go forward and use the newer more semantic elements for your layout - *header*, *section*, *footer* etc. and resort to *table*-s when you want to present some tabular data only.

Comment: I have this question, too, about whether he is using it as a crutch in place of missing skill (with all due respect, of course).

Comment: +1 for mention of HTML semantic elements - very underutilized.

Comment: How is it an ugly hack?  It's there for a reason:  to be used -- including on semantic elements like *header*, *section*, *footer*, etc.

Comment: @cimmanon this is an ugly hack in *this* particular situation - it's not appropriate to dumb down your code by hacking the natural flow of other semantic elements into table-like behavior because you're familiar using just that technique

Comment: You still haven't explained why using `display: table-cell` is dumb, but mucking around with floats isn't.  Either way, you're altering the element's natural flow.  The fact that the display property names contain the word "table" in them is your only real aversion to using them.

Comment: @cimmanon `display: table-cell` isn't dumb at all when used properly. As I said it's not appropriate in **this** situation when the OP ( with all the respect ) wants to use it as shortcut.

Comment: @cimmanon My point is - the OP knows how to use tables for the layout but agrees that that's a very faulty technique, so he wants to do it with *divs* etc. which is the correct way. But using semantic elements/tags just for the sake of using those, in the same time making them behave like a table destroys the whole point of applying them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to fear or loathe `display: table`. Yes, the value is `table`, but it is fair game and entirely valid CSS 2.1.

Tables are "bad" in markup, because they were abused and applied in a way that did not reflect their intended semantic purpose, which is to present tabular data. If you have tabular data, not using tables would be just as big a sin as using tables for layout.

Let's return to the topic though. Support for `display: table` is a bit flaky in IE < 8 and non-existent in Android < 2.1 and iOS < 3.2. If you need to support those, rather use `float`.

The simplest use of this property is to apply `display: table` to the parent element, `display: table-row` to the children and `display: table-cell` to the grand-children. If you deviate from this at any level, the results can get a bit weird. (I have personal experience with this.) Take a look at the W3C specification for the CSS table model if you get stuck.

**Sources:**
http://caniuse.com/css-table
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display

Comment: You're free to not set parent/grand-parent elements to `table` or `table-row` and just use `table-cell` on adjacent siblings.  The browser will generate anonymous tables/rows to contain them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. While CSS divs are the best solution for anything in HTML (except when you need IE6 support...), and tables (in terms of markup) are becoming an ancient technology, on the one hand it is possible to come up with the most handicapped and stupid solution on CSS ever made, and on the other hand you can create an HTML masterpiece without a single div.

So if you think you're good enough in CSS, use it. If you're not sure, or you're a real tables master, tables should do the work.

Comment: I would disagree that CSS divs are the best solution for anything.  Tables are often the best solution for things like - displaying tabular data (GASP). Tables and CSS are not an either/or proposition.  You can use CSS to style tables and you can use table-like displays for divs.  In fact, many of the very best javascript table functionality libraries rely on HTML table structures.  So to summarize, use the mark-up elements best-suited for displaying a particular set of content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never used `display: table`, but this link seems to be pretty well versed on the syntax.

http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout

I typically stick to floats and after reading this, might give `display: table` a chance. When I use floats, I have to follow it up with some sort of `clear: both` div. `display: table` seems to be a more efficient and acceptable solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned tables work great for tabular data.  I also like to use tables at times when you are getting a lot of dynamic data back.  For template development, I would stick with CSS.